Can I exchange this maximum with this sum?
Suppose I have nonnegative real numbers $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$, where the indices $i$ and $j$ belong to some finite set $N$. For $j$ fixed, I know that:
$$\sum_{i\in N}a_{ij}b_{ij} \le \max_{k\in N}\sum_{i \in N}a_{ik}b_{ij}$$
and this implies:
$$\sum_{i,j \in N}a_{ij}b_{ij} \le \sum_{j\in N}\max_{k\in N}\sum_{i\in N}a_{ik}b_{ij}.$$
My question is: can I exchange the sum and the maximum in the last expression so to obtain:
$$\sum_{i,j \in N}a_{ij}b_{ij} \le \max_{k\in N}\sum_{i,j \in N}a_{ik}b_{ij}$$
or not?

Final expression is not true. Take $N=\{1,2\}$, and $a_{11}=a_{22}=1$, $a_{12}=a_{21}=2$, and $b_{ij}=a_{ij}$ for all $i,j\in N$.
We get
$$
\sum_{i,j\in N}a_{ij}b_{ij}=1+4+4+1=10
$$
and
$$
\max_{k\in N}\sum_{i,j\in N}a_{ik}b_{ij}=\max(1+2+4+2,2+4+2+1)=9
$$
Some intuition why the final inequality does not hold: in this situation you have $\sum \max \geq \max \sum$ (try and prove this!), which has the reverse sign from what you need to prove the final inequality.
